# Pass hive a createTables.hql in batch mode

Tags: database, hadoop, hql, hive

I have created a huge `createTables.hql` file. However, I would like to give hive the file in batch mode to save a lot of time at implementation.

I tried `% hive -f createTables.hql`, however, that does nothing when saved in an `*.sh` file

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the script file has `execute` permission for the user who is running it from the command line. If not, use the `chmod` command to grant it.

You can then use the following command to run the script.
`Prompt> hive -v -f ./createTables.sh`

Comment: Is is also possible to convert the `*.hql` file into an executable file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a list of sql files (with commands)
Like,
create_table.sql , insert_table.sql etc.
I create a runscript.sh file with

```
    hive -f create_table.sql
    hive -f insert_table.sql

    chmod a+x runscript.sh.
```

:)